# Is it possible to include Jaxa Earth API to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis, google-ajax-api

I'm currently working on ArcGIS Pro and I wanted to know if it is possible to include the Jaxa Earth API in the program, as it is possible in QGIS really eady with the plugin. I can't find any information about it. Thank you!